# Combining Graphics, Graphics3D, and ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I'm trying to generate a figure similar to the first figure of  [enter link description here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.00075.pdf),
so I tried to draw a torus, a disk, and a tube which is tangent to the torus. The disk must be inside the torus. But apparently Graphics and Parametricplot3D or Graphics3D cannot be combined using Show. Of course, I will need to change parameters so they fit well, but I have no idea how to combine them. Here is the code:

```
f1 = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[2 t] (10 + Cos[2 u]), 
Sin[2 t] (10 + Cos[2 u]), Sin[2 u]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> {150, 150}, 
Mesh -> None]

f2 = Graphics[{Green, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}]

f3 = Graphics3D[
{Cyan, Tube[{{-5, 1, 0}, {5, 1, 0}}, 0.1]}, Boxed -> False, 
ImageSize -> 300]

Show[f1,f2,f3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is combining `Graphics` with `Graphics3D`. MMA isn't sure how to do that since the `Graphics` object is only defined in two dimensions. Switch it to `Graphics3D` instead, and use a `Cylinder[]` with a very small height.

```
f2 = Graphics3D[{Green, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.001}}, 10]}]
```

Re-run your code and we get:

[image: Microtorus build from Graphics3D.]